# postfix/sendmail[4825]: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]

Tags: email, sh

I am new in shell script,I have try to send mail using shell script as below code

```
from="test@mail.com"
to="recive@mail.com"
subject="Title here"
body="This is the body of our email"
declare -a attachments
attachments=( 'test.doc')

declare -a attargs
for att in "${attachments[@]}"; do
attargs+=( "-a"  "$att" )  
done

/usr/sbin/sendmail -s "$subject" -r "$from" "${attargs[@]}" "$to" <<< "$body"
```

Try to run in console show this type of error

```
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
sendmail: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
```

And mail log show this type error
    postfix/sendmail[4825]: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]

Answer (score 1):

`sendmail` is giving you the answer in the error message: `invalid option -- 's'`, which is in fact the case. There is no `-s` option to `sendmail` as `sendmail` is generally not considered a **command-line** mail program.

You will serve yourself much better using `mailx` or `heirloom-mailx` or the like. (it is the same program, it has just shuffled names over the past several years). It may already be installed on your system. Check with `type mailx`

For use/options see: [**mailx(1) - Linux man page**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx)

Comment: Actually `sendmail` is very commonly used from the command line, but it expects a complete, properly formatted RFC822 message as its input. But indeed, the options used by the OP look like options for some variant of `mailx`.  (There are many variants, which are incompatible in interesting and infuriating ways.)

Comment: While it may be true that it is difficult to find a standards compliant mailer, it is even more difficult to find a standards compliant mail **user**... Trying to use sendmail from the command line just seems like an awkward task when the nail/mailx package goes out of its way to accommodate the non-standards compliant user `:p`

Comment: I agree with your answer in general, just pointing out that "`sendmail`is generally not considered a command-line mail program" isn't strictly true; and also pointing out that the `mailx` the user may happen to have on their system doesn't necessarily accept those options either.  The traditional `mailx` doesn't support attachments, for example.